# Is it possible to change the background color of all incoming emails in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I have been working with the theme options in Gmail. There is an option for changing the background color of the text/background inbox list of emails. I would like to change the original background color of the emails when they are viewed. I do not like the strong white color in the emails and would prefer a graytone to reduce the brightness.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like Stylish for this. (It's available [for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/hu/firefox/addon/stylish/) and [for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe).) Then depending on your level of CSS skills you can use a theme that fits your needs, or create a new one that changes exactly what you want to change.